# Powershell RegEx assistance

Tags: regex, powershell

hoping somebody can help me out here.
Current string:

```
$monthlist = @()
$monthlist = Get-ChildItem $place -Recurse -Directory -force `
| Where-Object { ($_.name -match '((\\0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(200[0-9]|20[1-4][0-9]|205[0-5]))') }
```

This returns in Powershell:

```
C:\temp\test\10-2021
C:\temp\test\12-2019
C:\temp\test\2019\12-2019
C:\temp\test\2020\11-2020
```

But not:

```
c:\temp\test\08-2021 
c:\temp\test\09-2021
```

Using https://regex101.com/ and https://regexr.com/ they both say all 6 of the folders listed above should be matching.

I need the \ in the regex string due to there also being several folders such as the following that I do **not** want to match:

```
c:\temp\test\01-01-2021
c:\temp\test\05-25-2020
```

I'm not the best at RegEx and I'm hoping somebody can spot my error pretty quick

Comment: Remove the ```\\``` at the start of the first nested group - the path separator is not part of the file name itself

Comment: aside - the backtick at the end of your 2nd line is NOT needed. just move the pipe from the start of line 3 to the end of line 2.

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen if I pull the \\ then regex returns 10-01-2021 and 10-02-2021, which I need excluded.

Comment: @topcity36 You don't need ```\\``` for that, you just need to anchor the pattern against the start and end of the string: `$_.Name -match '^((0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(200[0-9]|20[1-4][0-9]|205[0-5]))$'`

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen sonuva....I could have sworn I'd tried that before.  Either way, it worked, thanks for the assist.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\\` in front of the first group prevents matching against names that start with `0`.

If you're worried about matching a substring that's part of a larger string (like `01-2021` in `01-01-2021`), make sure you anchor the pattern against the `^` start-of-string and `$` end-of-string metacharacters:

```
... | Where-Object { ($_.name -match '^((0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(200[0-9]|20[1-4][0-9]|205[0-5]))$') }
```

Comment: What if I wanted to pull \ from the string would it be like?



`Where-Object { ($_.name -match '^\\(((0[1-9]|1[0-2])-(200[0-9]|20[1-4][0-9]|205[0-5]))$)') }`

Comment: The string will never contain a ```\``` - it's not a valid file name character, and you're operating on file names

Comment: Fair, but if I'm using .fullname it'd have \xxx\xxx\